Consequences of the Separating Hyperplane Theorem in Convex Optimization
I'm trying to get a better understanding of the "geometry" at play in building Convex Optimization theory. This leads me to my question: what theorems are consequences of the Hahn-Banach Separating Hyperplane Theorem? As one example, it appears that Farkas' Lemma can be proved using the Separating Hyperplane Theorem.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
